# WebView in not working on popup react-native?

Tags: react-native, webview

I have HTML data and this data got by my custom API and I tried to display this HTML on a popup. But WebView is not working on popup, what can I use to show HTML on popup. And if it is possible through WebView, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: have you ever tried to install react-native-inappbrowser-reborn ?

Comment: No i didn't Because this library does not support inner HTML.

Comment: you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-htmlview